# Scraping HTML data from website in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to scrape certain pieces of HTML data from certain websites, but I can't seem to scrape the parts I want. For instance I set myself the challenge of scraping the number of followers from [this blog](http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/), but I can't seem to do so.

I've tried using urllib, request, beautifulsoup as well as [Jam API](https://www.jamapi.xyz/).

Here's what my code looks like at the moment:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import json
import urllib2

html = urlopen('http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print soup
```

How would I go about pulling the number of followers in this instace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't grab the followers as it's a widget loaded by javascript.  You need to grab parts of the html by css class or id or by the element.

E.g:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

html = urlopen('http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

assert soup.h1.string == '\nLAW FOR ALL-M.MURALI MOHAN\n'
```